# Datatable as mail in C# console application

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create html from my dataset using the following code

```
    public static string getHtml(DataTable dataSet)
    {
        try
        {
            string messageBody = "<font>The following are the records: </font><br><br>";

            if (dataSet.Rows.Count == 0)
                return messageBody;
            string htmlTableStart = "<table style=\"float:left; border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" >";
            string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
            string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style =\"background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;\">";
            string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
            string htmlTrStart = "<tr style =\"color:#555555;\">";
            string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
            string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\" border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px;\">";
            string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";


            foreach (DataColumn dc in dataSet.Columns)
            {

                messageBody += htmlTableStart;
                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;
                messageBody += htmlTdStart + dc + htmlTdEnd;
                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

                foreach (DataRow Row in dataSet.Rows)
                {
                    messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrStart;
                    messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + Row["" + dc + ""] + htmlTdEnd;
                    messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrEnd;
                }
            }
            messageBody = messageBody + htmlTableEnd;


            return messageBody;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[image]

I want to render in a way that 
All different tables should come in horizontally. I tried **float:left** but when i use this html to be send in mail , **float-left** don't work

Can something be changed in code so that Tables come in hozizontally as[image]

Comment: do you want new table for each row from your database ?

Comment: Try to give the table a certain `width`. `style=\" ... width:600px ...\"`

Comment: Please, use a StringBuilder!

Comment: @sylwester No i don't want it to be in different tables but want to show my dataset in horizontal way

Comment: Your htmlTableStart and htmlTableEnd does not match: you will have one htmlTableStart  for each column and only one htmlTableEnd...

Comment: Thanks Guys I have done it.

Comment: @Ke7in: Thats fine. What helped you solving the problem? (Just for other readers)

Answer (score 1):

I completed my answer . here is the solution to convert dataset to html

```
public static string DataTableToHTML(DataTable dataSet)
        {
            mLogger.Error("DataTableToHTML -------> Start");
            try
            {
                string messageBody = "<font>Following corporate actions are not updated in Security Master: </font><br><br>";

                if (dataSet.Rows.Count == 0)
                    return messageBody;
                string htmlTableStart = "<table style=\"border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center;\" >";
                string htmlTableEnd = "</table>";
                string htmlHeaderRowStart = "<tr style =\"background-color:#6FA1D2; color:#ffffff;\">";
                string htmlHeaderRowEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTrStart = "<tr style =\"color:#555555;\">";
                string htmlTrEnd = "</tr>";
                string htmlTdStart = "<td style=\" border-color:#5c87b2; border-style:solid; border-width:thin; padding: 5px;\">";
                string htmlTdEnd = "</td>";

                messageBody += htmlTableStart;
                messageBody += htmlHeaderRowStart;
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dataSet.Columns)
                {
                    messageBody += htmlTdStart + dc + htmlTdEnd;

                } messageBody += htmlHeaderRowEnd;

                foreach (DataRow dr in dataSet.Rows)
                {
                    messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrStart;
                    foreach (DataColumn dc in dataSet.Columns)
                    {

                        messageBody = messageBody + htmlTdStart + dr["" + dc + ""] + htmlTdEnd;
                    }
                    messageBody = messageBody + htmlTrEnd;
                }

                messageBody = messageBody + htmlTableEnd;

                mLogger.Error("DataTableToHTML -------> End");
                return messageBody;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                mLogger.Error("Exception in DatatableToHTML" + ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```